# Monitoring rest API calls in java/spring rest

Tags: java

I have a use case where we implemented spring rest api calls like below

```
/customer/payment 
/customer/info
```

But I wanted to implement or design the system like how many users are hitting my API in a day per user
And what API they tried to access ?

As I know we have to intercept the request and read the headers and body of the request and store into some where by wring some other service.

Is it correct or something we have in spring framework it self ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html).  There's some additional reading available here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-http.

Comment: Thanks Riaan and got it . Is there any other way we can build like custom service by adding annotations on rest service method and any sample code stuff . I would help alot.

Comment: For that, you'll probably want to look at Interceptors instead - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging.